# Jquery - How to remove a function load if don't need it anymore

Tags: jquery, function, setinterval

what i'm trying to do is load a function "PX_Function_Code()" on my setinterval and to work for just 10 sec, if the function didn't was access in 10 sec to be removed, its any way to can do this ?

This is my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if($( "#PX_Data" ).html() < 10) {
        var PX_Data = $( "#PX_Data" ).html();
        $( "#PX_Data" ).text( parseInt(PX_Data)+1 );

        PX_Function_Code();
    }
}, PX_Delay);
```

What i need is something like this:

```
if($("#PX_Data").html() < 10 && Data_Test1 != "") {
 PX_Function_Code();
} else {
" remove PX_Function_Code function "
}
```

Comment: Code looks messy when you don't properly indent...

Comment: Can you include the PF_Function_Code in the question, please?

Comment: i update the code with what im searching...if is possible...

Answer (score 1):

```
var intervalid = setInterval( ... );
```

Then later, when you don't need it:

```
clearInterval(intervalid);
```